# Initializing 2D array to hold a list in each location

Tags: python, numpy

Can I create a numpy array that stores a list (initially empty) in each location?

According to the documentation, numpy arrays store homogeneous types, so I would imagine that this is possible. But I can I initialize one to hold empty lists?

If this is not possible with numpy arrays, what alternatives do I have? (what other 2D-matrix-like structures can I use to hold lists/dictionaries/tuples?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rarely a good idea, but what you are asking for is an array of object type:

```
>>> a = np.empty((5,), dtype=object)
>>> a
array([None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
>>> a[0] = []
>>> a
array([[], None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
>>> a[0].append(4)
>>> a
array([[4], None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple list comprehension if you know the length (which we'll call N), and then convert it to a numpy array:

```
>>> empty_array = numpy.array([[] for i in xrange(N)])
```